# How do I replace a delimiter that appears only in between something?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I have a use case with this data:

```
1. "apple+case"
2. "apple+case+10+cover"
3. "apple+case+10++cover"
4. "+apple"
5. "iphone8+"
```

Currently, I am doing this to replace the + with space as follows:

```
def normalizer(value: String): String = {
    if (value == null) {
      null
    } else {
       value.replaceAll("\\+", BLANK_SPACE)        
     }
  }

  val testUDF = udf(normalizer(_: String): String)

  df.withColumn("newCol",  testUDF($"value"))
```

But this is replacing all "+". How do I replace "+" that comes between strings while also handling use cases like: "apple+case+10++cover" =>  "apple case 10+ cover"?

```
The output should be
1. "apple case"
2. "apple case 10 cover"
3. "apple case 10+ cover"
4. "apple"
5. "iphone8+"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace` to do this instead of a udf, it should be much faster. For most of the cases, you can use negative lookahead in the regexp, but for "+apple" you actually want to replace "+" with "" (and not a space). The easiest way is to simply use to regexps.

```
df.withColumn("newCol", regexp_replace($"value", "^\\+", ""))
  .withColumn("newCol", regexp_replace($"newCol", "\\+(?!\\+|$)", " "))
```

This will give:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|value               |newCol              |
+--------------------+--------------------+
|apple+case          |apple case          |
|apple+case+10+cover |apple case 10 cover |
|apple+case+10++cover|apple case 10+ cover|
|+apple              |apple               |
|iphone8+            |iphone8+            |
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

---

To make this more modular and reusable, you can define it as a function:

```
def normalizer(c: String) = regexp_replace(regexp_replace(col(c), "^\\+", ""), "\\+(?!\\+|$)", " ")

df.withColumn("newCol", normalizer("value"))
```

Comment: The issue is I need to apply this across multiple DFs thats why thought UDF as cleaner approach. Please let me know if you any other cleaner and faster approach that way I can apply across multiple DFs

Comment: @user3407267: If you want to you can simply take the regexps and put them into your UDF, it should still work. But you can have the `regexp_replace` in a method as well (keeping the speed), I added a bit information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try making two regex replacements:

```
df.withColumn("newCol", regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(testUDF("value"), "(?<=\d)\+(?!\+)", "+ "),
    "(?<!\d)\+", " ")).show
```

The inner regex replacement would target the edge case of single plus preceded by a digit, which should be replaced by adding a space (but not deleting the plus).  Example:

```
apple+case+10+cover  -->  apple+case+10+ cover
```

The outer regex replacement then targets all pluses which are not preceded by a digit, and replaces them with a space.  Example, continuing from above:

```
apple+case+10+ cover -->  apple case 10+ cover
```

Comment: This doesn't replace "apple+case+10+cover" and "apple+case+10++cover" - testing via https://regex101.com This seems to work only for single "+"

Comment: I consider `apple+case+10+cover` to be bad data.  Do you really have this data?

Comment: Yes. Its one of common use case. Atleast I want ++ to replaced with single " " (worst case solution)

Comment: testUDF("value") should already replace all + in the string right ? should tat be outer ?

Comment: @user3407267 Please check the updated answer, it should work now.